# Why is Wolf's Rain so ridiculously expensive?

Tags: merchandise, wolfs-rain

I am looking to add the complete set of Wolf's Rain to my anime collection, however after shopping around on E-Bay I see the following:

[Wolf's Rain for over $300](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/172189579429?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true)

This is a pretty common price-point for Wolf's Rain, I constantly see that this series is starting at over $300. Why is this? From what I understand Wolf's Rain was never really a huge hit. So why does it cost so much to obtain a legitimate copy?

Comment: supply and demand

Comment: FYI, the last time a new copy was sold on amazon, it was sold at $90.55 at the end of March

Comment: @ton.yeung Wow that's crazy. Wolf's Rain is one of my all-time favorites. I thought there were some cool concepts, and am surprised it wasn't extremely popular. I just let a used copy slip away for $55... Should've nabbed it.

Comment: In Japan, Wolf's Rain ranked third among anime series airing in the same time slot behind Air Master and Dear Boys. The series was considered "a big hit in 2004" for the North American market, selling well in mass markets as well as in online markets and at independent retailers. ICv2 notes that it has "a strong appeal to the growing teen and older anime audience." The series was selected as one of the top ten anime properties of 2005 for the ICv2 Retailers Guide to Anime/Manga. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf%27s_Rain#Reception)

Comment: @ton.yeung Yeah but I don't think it's like Cowboy Bebop where you can walk into BestBuy 15 years later and see brand new copies on the shelves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the original run of *Wolf's Rain*, which is no longer in production, and as such is subject to secondhand supply and demand price increases.

I recommend that you look into the [Wolf's Rain - Complete Collection Limited Edition DVD Set](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/releases.php?id=5318) released in 2005. This set started at 149.99 and is listed on the related auctions on the link you provided to eBay for $195, a ~25% increase from its original price.